# Does the trim function in Oracle have limitations based on the datatype it handles?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format

I tried selecting records from a table using the query:

```
select *
  from TableA
 where trim(DateField)='31-Dec-2015'
```

which returned 0 rows.

However, leaving put the `trim` function gave me records matching my `where` condition. Can't point put the error.

Comment: Is DateField a DATE or a VARCHAR2?

Comment: Then you should cast the literal date into a DATE and you don't need the TRIM function. At most, you would need TRUNC, i.e: DateField = TO_DATE('31-Dec-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the trim and trunc functions. You also have data conversion issues. Dates should be compared to dates. By using trim you are forcing oracle to turn the date field into a string.

```
select * from TableA where trunc(DateField) = to_date('31-Dec-2015','dd-Mon-yyyy');
```

Better would be:

```
select * 
  from TableA 
 where DateField between to_date('31-Dec-2015','dd-Mon-yyyy')
                     and to_date('31-Dec-2015 23:59:59', 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: Yes I think the use of trim here is incorrect. Thanks!